# Java code design pattern for notification service

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have third party service providers for email and sms and now i am integrating it in my application .so before begin designing it i would like to get suggestion for best way of doing it .Here is my basic idea of doing it .I have two interfaces for Notification types and Recipient types.

```
public interface Notification {

    public int sendNotification(Recipient Recipient);

    public int deleteNotification(int notificationId);

}
```

and my SMS noty implementation would be like this

```
public class SMSnotification implements Notification{

    @Override
    public int sendNotification(Recipient Recipient) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int deleteNotification(int notificationId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Like this i will have other kind of notifications .

Please suggest me if anything could be added or modified in it .

Thanks :)

Comment: how do you call your provider API.

Comment: Hi Thang ,i have its Java REST Methods to be called .

Comment: You will need retry in case send email timeout. As you may have attachment.

Comment: Read about publish-subscribe pattern, it should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your recipient is not null before returning `sendNotification`

Comment: Its just the idea ,i ve mentioned here .I would like to know about the design and future complications with the above pattern .Thanks :)